# Laravel 6: How to change the URL of the password reset email link in custom class

Tags: api, laravel-6, reset-password

I'm building API with Laravel and working on resetting password. Everything is working fine but I want to change the URL which will handle the reset link to be different than the API domain

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
  Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController')->name('password.reset');

public function forgotPassword($data) {
    Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $data['email']]);
}
```

Laravel reset password class (class ResetPassword extends Notification)

```
 return (new MailMessage)
        ....
        ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), url(route('password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
        ....
}
```

I want to change the URL

```
http://api.test:8000/api/password/reset?token=dced9b55a73fcd0692ce4157d2685826f51c332d0dcce613cad108a8599881d7&email=user@mail.com
```

to be

```
http://frontend.test:8000/reset-password?token=dced9b55a73fcd0692ce4157d2685826f51c332d0dcce613cad108a8599881d7&email=user@mail.com
```

I managed to change it in the original class

```
// ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), url(route('password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), 'http://frontend.test:8000/reset-password?token='.$this->token.'&email='.$notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset())
```

But how can I override this function in my own class that would be better to keep the original function as it is but don't know how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a static helper in Laravel's ResetPassword notification, you can add following code in the App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider class:

```php
     use App\Notifications\Auth\ResetPasswordNotification;

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        ResetPasswordNotification::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
            return config('app.frontend_url')."/password/reset/$token?email={$notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()}";
        });

        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer here by creating a custom notification and using it in CanResetPassword trait https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-override-the-tomail-function-in-illuminateauthnotificationsresetpasswordphp